# Phonetisaurus dependency issue

Tags: raspberry-pi3, pocketsphinx

I am trying to install Phonetisaurus (using the Jasper installation instructions [here](https://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/installation/#installing-sphinx)). Unfortunatly I've run into a dependency issue I haven't been able to solve.

When I run the command `sudo apt-get -t experimental install phonetisaurus m2m-aligner mitlm libfst-tools` I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  m2m-aligner : Depends: libstdc++6 (>=5.2) but 4.9.2-10 is to be installed
  mitlm : Depends libmitlm0 (= 0.4.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libstdc++6 (>=5.2) but 4.9.2-10 is to be installed
phonetisaurus : Depends: libfst4 (>=1.5.3+r3) but it is not installable
                Depends: libstdc++6 (>=5.2) but 4.9.2-10 is to be installed
```

Attempting to install libstdc++6 directly (either with `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6` or `sudo apt-get -f libstdc++6`) leaves me with:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libstdc++6 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-atomic1.55.0 libboost-filesystem1.55.0
  libboost-program-options1.55.0 libboost-regex1.55.0 libboost-thread1.55.0
  libcwiid1 libfftw3-single3 libjs-prettify libqscintilla2-11
  libqscintilla2-l10n libqt4-network libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtwebkit4
  libruby1.9.1 libruby1.9.1-dbg libscsynth1 libtcltk-ruby1.9.1 ri1.9.1
  ruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1-dev ruby1.9.1-examples ruby1.9.1-full ruby1.9.3
  supercollider supercollider-common supercollider-ide supercollider-language
  supercollider-server supercollider-supernova
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 82 not upgraded.
```

Attempting to install libfst4 gives me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libfst4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libfst4' has no installation candidate
```

And attempting to install libmitlm0 gives me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmitlm0 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.9.2-10 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I feel like there is something I'm missing here but after a day of messing around with it I still can't figure it out. Any help/insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Jasper document is outdated and not realy useful.

Comment: Don't use experimental repo, compile phonetisaurus from code.

Comment: After looking over the CMUSphinx site I think I'll be going with the Sequence-to-Sequence G2P toolkit, since that seems to be more up-to-date. Thank you for the tips though.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I tried downloading the source but it return 404 error.  


`    wget http://distfiles.macports.org/openfst/openfst-1.3.3.tar.gz
    wget https://mitlm.googlecode.com/files/mitlm-0.4.1.tar.gz
    wget https://m2m-aligner.googlecode.com/files/m2m-aligner-1.2.tar.gz
    wget https://phonetisaurus.googlecode.com/files/is2013-conversion.tgz`

Comment: download phonetisaurus from link https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/phonetisaurus/is2013-conversion.tgz and openfst from http://www.openfst.org/twiki/pub/FST/FstDownload/openfst-1.3.4.tar.gz. you do not need mitlm and m2m-aligner to compile phonetisaurus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks G10DRAS for providing the link.

This solution worked for me. First, I downloaded these files

```
sudo wget https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/phonetisaurus/is2013-conversion.tgz
sudo wget http://www.openfst.org/twiki/pub/FST/FstDownload/openfst-1.3.4.tar.gz
```

Then, untared the files

```
tar -xvf is2013-conversion.tgz
tar -xvf openfst-1.3.4.tar.gz
```

Finally, following next steps at: [http://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/installation](http://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/installation/)

Comment: This seems to have worked, however I can't move the files that the installation guide tells me to. I keep getting a `cp: cannot stat _filename_ no such file or directory` error.

Comment: Never mind, I forgot I'm building this in a sub-directory and the move command won't work without adjusting the file path to reflect that.